# Magento 1 to Magento 2 Data Migration causing Validation Exception error

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, error, ssh, data-migration-tool

I'm currently in the process of trying to migrate my Magento 1 data to Magento 2.

The versions are Magento 1.9.3.9 for the original and Magento 2.2.7 for the new one.

I have cloned the Magento 1 database onto my Magento 2 site location and modified the config file in the following location:

> httpdocs / vendor / magento / data-migration-tool / etc /
>   opensource-to-opensource / 1.9.3.9 / config.xml

and configured it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="original-database-name" user="username" password="password" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="new-database-name" user="username" password="password"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.3.9</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
<crypt_key><![CDATA[1234567abcdef]]></crypt_key>

    </options>
</config>
```

The problem now is when I run the following command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml
```

I get the following error

[image]

I'm assuming that this is an error with the database names but I'm not sure what as they seem to be named correctly.

If anyone knows why this error is occurring I would appreciate any information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching it seems that the error was being caused by an ampersand "&" symbol in the password field. I have amended this now and this particular error does not seem to be happening anymore.